# Hello there, I am a newbie with Google script, trying to coding an automatic Send Email function. Want to skip any empty rows so the function continue

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  for (var i = 2; i <= lr; i++) {
    var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    var currentTitle = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
    GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, currentTitle, "Hi")
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please checkout [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
function sendEmail() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  //Get all the values with one call into memory
  var values = ss.getRange(2, 2, ss.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();

  //Loop over the array or rows and destructure the values.
  values.forEach(value => {
    const [email, title] = value
    //check if email is not empty string. If so then skip.
    if (email == "") {
      return
    }
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, title, "Hi")
  })
}
```